# CouchDB legal characters for usernames in the _users DB

Tags: url, character-encoding, couchdb

What are the legal characters that can be used in a username for the CouchDB _users database? And if there are special characters, can they be encoded in the URL and then be decoded by CouchDB? I am having a hard time finding this info. I would like to use email addresses for usernames, but there are a lot of legal characters in an email address that URLs don't like and CouchDB may not.

Thanks,

Warren Bell

Comment: Are you asking about CouchDB or Couchbase?  You have it tagged as both.

Comment: CouchDB, just thought some of the Couchbase people may know the answer

Comment: They are different pieces of software. Think of it like MySQL and SQL Server. They both have the same acronym in their names, but I wouldn't generally expect a SQL Server person to be able to answer a MySQL question.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam/issues/4) is a link about couchbeam, its not CouchDB, but the issue talks about special characters in CouchDB. I don't have an answer for you, but this may help. And when in doubt, try creating documents with all the special characters and see what sticks.

Comment: I just ended up testing different characters like Hypnic Jerk suggested  and found out that there are a lot of characters that are not legal. So I decided to use usernames that are lowercase and only use alphanumeric characters no spaces.